# OpenCL clCreateCommandQueue memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

In my application I have a lot of time initialize OpenCL, which causes a memory leak. Here is a small example of code causing the leak:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main()
{
    cl_platform_id platform = 0;
    cl_int err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if(err != CL_SUCCESS){ return 1; }

    cl_device_id device_id = 0;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    if(err != CL_SUCCESS){ return 2; }

    char buff[128];
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, buff, NULL);
    if(err != CL_SUCCESS){ return 3; }
    fprintf(stdout, "Device Name: %s\n", buff);

    while(true)
    {
        cl_context context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
        if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
            return 4;
    
        cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);
        if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
            return 5;
    
        clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);

        clReleaseContext(context);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is part of the example from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Introduction/Intro.html). And without `cl_command_queue` initialization doesn't lead to leak. Where is the problem?

My configuration: Radeon R7 250, AMD APP SDK 3.0, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: If `clCreateCommandQueue` fails you won't release the context.

Comment: @Dutow Yes, I tried to minimize the code for ease of understanding.The leak is very small, and it becomes apparent after more than a hundred times cycles of operation. So I can say that the loop will not be interrupted.

Comment: I tired this on GTX 970, HD 4600 and RX 480 and the RX 480 is only one that leaks memory. Would recommend trying the AMD OpenCL forums

Comment: @Jovasa Thank you! This is a good test that allow to look at the other side of the problem.

Comment: @Jovasa Tell me, do you ran it on different machines? Which AMD driver is installed?

Comment: @AlexTeos The 970 and 480 were on a same machine while the HD 4600 was in a different machine. Drivers are crimson 16.7.1 I believe might have been 16.7.2. Can't check right now

Comment: valgrind reports "definitely lost: 25,092 bytes in 86 blocks" even for single "clCreateCommandQueue/clReleaseCommandQueue" invocation. I use AMDAPPSDK-3.0.130.136 in Ubuntu